# Excluding Links from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to start off by saying I am very very new to javascript, and basically did a lot of googling to find this place and various other resources. While I found a script to modify into something I wanted (and managed to get it to work) it interferes with any links that are made within the specified div. Is there a way to exclude the links from the javascript, and just have the javascript affect the text?

This is the javascript. While I have no problem getting the first part to work (where I replace quoted text), I can't seem to exclude links and images that has html which possesses quotation marks in them.

```
$("div.gam-posttem div").each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\"([^\"]+)\"/g, 
        '<div class="gam-quotetext">"$1"</div>');
});
$not('div.gam-posttem > div > a').each(function(){});
```

And here's the html I am using.

```
<div class="gam-posttem"><div class="gam-posttem1">

"quote here" and regular text here. "more quote here"

<br><br><a href="http://www.google.com">Link is Here</a>

</div></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if you need any more info, such as CSS, please feel free to ask.

Comment: what exactly do you want the javascript to do with your links?

Comment: May be able to update regex to avoid text inside of tags otherwise use inner loop to skip over tags

Answer (score 0):

What makes this particularly tricky is that JavaScript Regular Expressions do not allow look-behind. What you want to do is try and match " pairs where there are an equal number of < and > characters (outside of other " characters) before it. And even if you could, that'd be a pretty nasty looking regex...

However, you only care about characters outside of <> pairs, which matching using Regex (while not advisable) is possible:
`<(?:[^><\"\']*?(?:([\"\']).*?\1)?[^><\'\"]*?)+(?:>|$)` will match all <> pairs, ignoring close angle brackets within quotes within the tag. Hence you want to match everything outside these tags.

There's probably a better way to do this, but you can try the following idea:

1. Match all tags
2. For each tag, get the start position and length => calculate end position
3. add the start index of the string to the front of the end positions
4. add the length of the string to the start positions
5. for each (end, start) pair (as we are inverting the matches), run your replace method and modify the string.

```js
String.prototype.spliceish = function(start, end, newSubStr) {
  return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(end);
};

var tagMatch = /<(?:[^><\"\']*?(?:([\"\']).*?\1)?[^><\'\"]*?)+(?:>|$)/g;
var tokenMatch = /\"([^\"]+)\"/g;

function invertedMatch(htmlString) {
 var returnString = htmlString;
 var startIndexes = [],
   lengths = [],
    match = tagMatch.exec(htmlString);
  while(match !== null)
  {
   startIndexes.push(match.index);
    lengths.push(match[0].length);
    match = tagMatch.exec(htmlString);
  }
  
  var endIndexes = startIndexes.map(function(val, ix) { return val + lengths[ix]; });
  var invertedStarts = [0].concat(endIndexes); // we are inverting, so capture start text.
  var invertedEnds = startIndexes.concat(htmlString.length);
  
  // will need to go backwards
  for(var i = invertedStarts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var start = invertedStarts[i],
     end = invertedEnds[i];
   var stringReplace = htmlString.substring(start, end);
    returnString = returnString.spliceish(start, end, stringReplace.replace(tokenMatch,
     '<div class="gam-quotetext">"$1"</div>'));
  };
  
  return returnString;
}

$("#root").html(invertedMatch($("#root").html()));
```

```css
.gam-quotetext{
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div class="gam-posttem">
    <div class="gam-posttem1">

    "quote here" and regular text here. "more quote here"

    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Link is Here</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, while I can get this to work perfectly in JSFiddle and whatnot, I can't seem to get it to work on my site, which is a Jcink forum. Do I wrap the javascript in simple <script> tags, and do I put the code you have above the divs in the <head>? I am sorry for all the questions, I am just very new to javascript and how to go about it.

Comment: I don't know anything about Jcink, unfortunately, but if your page data is coming from somewhere else, the above code may be running too early. Try putting the Script tag with the javascript in it at the bottom of the body, and perhaps wrap the jQuery section within `$(document).ready()`